# Pass dictionary data to Django view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm confused on how to set up/call my url to pass a dictionary of data from my template to my view. I'm getting an error "NoReverseMatch at /categories/academy/" How can I pass `data_dict`, which is a dictionary, to my view?

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:request_access' data_dict %}" class="btn btn-green btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Join Group</a>
```

urls.py

```
# the category_slug in this case is "academy", see the error I mentioned above
url(r'^categories/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/request_access/$', 'request_access', name='request_access')
```

views.py

```
def request_access(request, data):
    print("DJANGO VIEW- THIS IS NOT PRINTING")
    mydata = request.GET.get('data_dict')  # will this work?
    # do other stuff
    return render(request, 'polls/categories/group_access_requested.html',
        {'data': request})
```

Comment: Where did this data_dict come from? In most cases it makes more sense to store data in the user session. If you put it in a url, you have to translate the dictionary into url parameters in some way. You could pickle/json-dump the dictionary and store it in the database, and then use a hash or uuid to put in the url. `http://example.com/categories/foo/request_access/AD5dsf431234s52/`

`AD5dsf431234s52` is then used as a pk or unique slug to rebuild the dictionary from storage in your database or something like redis.

Comment: This is similar to the links you will get when you click 'I forgot my password' on many web pages. The url only contains a unique and unguessable string that is connected to some value stored on the server. Session cookies in django also use a similar key scheme. It's not stored in the url, but in a client side cookie.

Comment: Thank you so much @HåkenLid This is a great explanation- I will try this route once/if my current approach fails (trying to encode the url parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a decorator to perform the encoding of the data_dict.

```
import urllib
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_encoded_dict(data_dict):
    return urllib.urlencode(data_dict)
```

Then inside your template, you can use it as:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:request_access' my_category_slug %}?{{data_dict|get_encoded_dict}}" class="btn btn-green btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Join Group</a>
```

This ought to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm so close now! I now see my data being passed in the url. However, I get a 404 error:

`Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/categories/request_access/?category=Academy&profile=jwilliams
No Category matches the given query.`

Comment: I guess in your template you need something like: 
`<a href="/categories/{{data_dict.category|slugify}}/request_access/?{{data_dict|get_encoded_dict}}" class="btn btn-green btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Join Group</a>`

Comment: Yes! It works! This is wonderful- thank you soooo much @animeshsharma

Answer (score 1):

To pass parameters to a url in a template, you will have to encode the parameters and then attach it at the end of the url.

You need to do something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:request_access' my_category_slug %}?key1=value1&key2=value2.." class="btn btn-green btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Join Group</a>
```

Another option is to use [`urllib.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) from [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) library to encode the dictionary to url-encoded parameters. Just pass a dictionary to it and it will convert it to url-encoded string.

```
In [1]: import urllib

In [2]: data_dict = {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'}

In [3]: urllib.urlencode(data_dict)
Out[3]: 'key3=value3&key2=value2&key1=value1'
```

Then you can pass this url-encoded string to the context as `my_url_encoded_string` and place it at the end of the url.

In your views, then you can access the `data_dict` by its keys.

```
value1 = request.GET.get('key1') # value of 'key1'
value2 = request.GET.get('key2') # value of 'key2'
```

Comment: I'm trying your first suggestion to encode the parameters and attaching them to the end of the url. Keep getting an error `TypeError at /categories/academy/request_access/` . Am still trying and will post again when/if I make progress soon

Comment: my button/link: `<a href="{% url 'polls:request_access' category.slug %}?profile=profile&category=category" class="btn btn-green btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Join Group</a>`

Comment: url: `url(r'^categories/(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/request_access/$', 'request_access',
        name='request_access'),`

and the first line of the view:
`def request_access(request, parent_slug):`

Comment: What was the complete error you received i.e. next line after `TypeError`?

Comment: It was: `uest_access() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category_slug'`

Comment: I think it should be `def request_access(request, category_slug):` in your view definition. Change `parent_slug` to `category_slug`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Ajax for that. Here's an example to base your code off of:

**html:**

```
# Instead of passing info through here, I would set something up in your model to handle that
<a href="{{ object.get_some_url }} class="ajax_call" data="enter_value_here">Join Group</a>
```

**models.py:**

```
class Model(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel)

    def get_some_url(self):
        return reverse('url_name',
                       kwargs={'url_argument': self.field.value})
```

**ajax:**

```
$('.ajax_call').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'some_url' %}",
        data: {
            "data_to_be_sent": $(this).attr("data"),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.worked) {
                // Do something here
            } else {
                // Do something else here
            }
        },
        error: function (rs, e) {
            alert('Sorry, there was an error.');
        }
    });
});
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

from datetime import datetime


@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def textbook(request):
    data_received = request.POST.get('data_to_be_sent')
    # Do something with this data
    if something_was_done:
        # Do something?
        worked = True
    else:
        # Do something else?
        worked = False

    data = {
        'worked': worked
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @jape - I did originally want to use Ajax but, after many attempts, I couldn't get it to work so I gave up for a simpler approach:(

Comment: @steph No problem. The best approach you can take is to get everything working, then refactor and improve. Don't worry about the down vote - some people stink. Save my response for later when you get more advanced. As long as you benefit from it in the long run, nothing else matters. Best of luck!