# Django: Passing an Object Variable from html form to views

Tags: python, django

I have a list of nested dictionaries that I am iterating through to create a html list.
Each list entry has button, which on submit should trigger a function on views.py to create a django model object. How do I pass pass a dictionary as the post data when the button is pressed?

```
    {% if NewStudentsExists %}
        <div class="container-fluid m-3">
            <h3>New Students</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid m-1">
            <ul class="list-group">
                {% for NewStudent in NewStudents %}
                    <li class="list-group-item">{{ NewStudent.name }}

                        <div class="float-right m-1">
                            <form action="{% url 'add_student' %}" action="post">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" {{ NewStudent.Added }}>
                                    Add
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889635/pass-dictionary-data-to-django-view) help?